# Purpose of HNONSEC signal in M33 System?

Tags: arm, cortex-m, trustzone

I have been looking into subsystems that make use of the ARM M33 TrustZone features and secure peripherals.

From what I have read the SAU and/or IDAU define the addresses in the system that are secure, non-secure callable and non-secure.

I have read from page 27 of an ST presentation

https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/group1/cb/51/2d/35/77/d5/40/02/STM32L5_Security_Trustzone_TRZ/files/STM32L5_Security_Trustzone_TRZ.pdf/_jcr_content/translations/en.STM32L5_Security_Trustzone_TRZ.pdf

that:
"Non-secure access towards secure area is automatically blocked at SAU/IDAU level."

I am confused then what the purpose of the AHB5 HNONSEC signal is?

If the M33 running in a non-secure state accesses a secure address in a peripheral it will be blocked automatically by the SAU/IDAU so HNONSEC is not required.

Is the HNONSEC only required in the case where the SAU could have been programmed incorrectly. So a peripheral that is intended to be secure but is marked as non-secure in the SAU still blocks non-secure accesses due to seeing HNONSEC=1?

Is there any other examples/senarios of how this HNONSEC signal increases security in a way that is not already done by the SAU/IDAU?

I expected the SAU/IDAU to just simply set the value of value of the HNONSEC signal and it would be a secure peripherals responsibility to block any non-secure accesses. However, it seems the SAU/IDAU does this blocking itself.

Comment: You have read the arm documentation yes?

Comment: I've read the AMBA AHB5 Protocol Spec and the Security Attribution and Memory Protection section of the M33 technical manual. Is there another document that would help here?